# How can I fix the following error: exited with code=1?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to download c# on visual studios. When I run it, it throws me this code. I've downloaded cscript and the other necessary applications. It should work, but it doesn't.

My code is as follows

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");    
    }
  }
}
```

I moved the file containing my c# "Hello World" into the dotnet SDK as visual studios was giving me a warning saying that dotnet SDK was not downloaded. However, it has been.

Comment: Just open the VS installer and choose the modules you want. You probably want to start with .Net Desktop development. Everything you need is in that installer.